# Convert images to csv file as a data point

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have an images dataset folder contaning 1300+ jpeg files, i want to convert these images to csv file, but each image is placed in csv as data point mean each image place in row of csv file.

Discribe any method which is faster and efficient.

Thanks

i tri some method bust it not work perfectly

Comment: why do you want to convert images to csv? it's not efficient at all.

Comment: it's not too necessarily that efficient but how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a way to save you images to csv, after hours of trying I figured out a way.
Let's say you have all you images in a folder called images:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Get all the paths
image_files = []
extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']
for ext in extensions:
    image_files.extend(glob.glob("images/*." + ext))
image_files

#Convert images into arrays and then to string.
#I also want to save its shapes in order to restore them.
image_arrays = []
image_shapes = []
for file in image_files:
    img = Image.open(file)
    img_array = np.array(img, dtype=str)
    img_shape = img_array.shape
    image_arrays.append("_".join(list(img_array.flatten())))
    image_shapes.append(img_shape)

#create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "path": image_files,
    "image": image_arrays,
    "image_shape": image_shapes
})

df.to_csv("my_images.csv", index=None) #save it to csv
```

Now if you want to restore them. Let's restore here the first one:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv("my_images.csv")
my_image_shape = eval(df2.image_shape[0])
my_image = df2.image[0]
my_image_arr = np.array([int(i) for i in my_image.split("_")], dtype=np.uint8)
my_image_arr = my_image_arr.reshape(my_image_shape) 

#with this you have converted the image into a numpy array
#you save this image
my_img = Image.fromarray(my_image_arr)
my_img.save("greatimage.jpg")
```

Give it a like, it took me hours to investigate.

Comment: I can tell you, this is not efficient at all. CSVs are not for that. But you insisted, so I investigated this for you.